# Android : How to write the data to firebase in background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I m creating an app that run in background which writes its current location details to the firebase database in periodic interval of time (i.e. it will writes for every minute.). Initially i will write the location detail to location.txt file for every minute.
After i did the same for for writing to the firebase instead of writing to the text file but, it will write for the first three times only then it won't write. I couldn't figure out how to write it constantly until i stop.

I m yet to upload the code but here it will shows the error (Indentation is required)...

Please help on this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you sure that your background task/service is not killed by the system?
try to print a log instead of saving data to firebase database, just to see if the task is still running after 3 minutes.

Comment: yeah i put a log message before initializing and after updating data to firebase,

Comment: but it will updates exactly 3 times after that it won't @Wilik

Comment: so maybe the system kills it. Is your service set to foreground?

Comment: No I put a log message there that message will be printed, But it wont updates the firebase after 3 minutes

Comment: what I mean was, if you delete your firebase save data code and leaves only log printing code, will the task killed after 3 minutes? is it a service or a thread?

Comment: No @Wilik it will print the the log properly even if i delete the save data code.

Comment: ok, it looks like the service is killed then, can you provide the code? are you repeating the task using AlarmManager or a runnable? you can try to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Okay  Here is the Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227450/android-firebase-update-issue-when-the-app-is-in-background/38229289?noredirect=1#comment63890037_38229289