# Emulator in Android Studio with Google Play services out of date

Tags: android, firebase, android-emulator, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

When I try to run my app with Firebase in an emulator, I get these error messages constantly:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9879480
```

I updated everything that Android Studio asked me to update, I created a new emulator with API 25... But it's still not working.

I can neither do it from the emulator:

[image]

Does anyone know how to update Google Play Services on Android emulators?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41100106/4815718

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Gradle scripts > build.gradle** change version of Google play services to 9.8.0 in dependencies.