# Firebase Android Load image to ImageView from storage

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Firebase app. Without picasso i want to load uploaded images.
I found the next solution:

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

When i try to use it:

Here is my Firebase Storage URL: `gs://teszt-cd548.appspot.com`
I created an `images` folder and uploaded `cross.png` image.

Storage location

```
gs://teszt-cd548.appspot.com/images/cross.png
```

When i try to load it on android:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://teszt-cd548.appspot.com");
StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("images/cross.png");

Glide.with(context)
       .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
       .load(pathReference)
       .into(iv);
```

Here is my rule:

```
  service firebase.storage {
  match /b/teszt-cd548.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read;
       allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I got the next error message on android:

```
StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
01-14 18:42:46.104 31019-31093/com.app.myapplication E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Anyone have idea about this error?

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and that happens because your Google play services are out of date my solution is to use a real updated device, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100106/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-10084000-but-found-9879470-cant-upd) to find more ways to solve your problem and a better explanation.