# W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

The project is a chat client through Firebase. It started when I deleted my database. I had too many test users, messages I wanted to clear it. Since then, it gets a million error notifications - trying to fix one thing leads to even worse errors.

I had a lot of different errors in my project. I tried to fix it with the help of stackoverflow. But from what I analyzed - it all comes down to an error:

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

I tried to connect to the application completely different base, I tried to re-arrange a few things. Nothing helps. I tried to change versions of google-services. I went through:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

Because I read in other threads that this is a known bug that was repaired in a higher version google-services. But I'm not sure if it works. My emulator supports only 9.8.79 Google Play Services so anything above that should not work. But a drowning man will clutch at a straw. 
[image]

I tried to create a completely new project with the code 100% copied from the tutorial. Always gets the same error. I think that if you copy the code from the internet it should all work. There is nothing wrong with the code, but something is wrong with Gradle. I have everything updated, I installed again Android Studio.

If this helps, I can not turn on the 2 emulators at the same time. The second is then loaded then switches itself off.Installing Android Studio again not fix this error.

**build.gradle (project)**

```
dependencies 
{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
```

**build.gradle (module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rachel.komunikator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Android Monitor with filter "firebase"**

```
02-02 23:07:18.374 21212-21283/com.example.rachel.komunikator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-02 23:07:18.386 21212-21212/com.example.rachel.komunikator D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
02-02 23:07:18.409 21212-21212/com.example.rachel.komunikator I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                      adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.example.rachel.komunikator
02-02 23:07:18.410 21212-21283/com.example.rachel.komunikator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-02 23:07:18.440 21212-21212/com.example.rachel.komunikator I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
02-02 23:07:18.761 21212-21212/com.example.rachel.komunikator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4
02-02 23:07:18.761 21212-21212/com.example.rachel.komunikator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 4
02-02 23:07:28.891 21212-21283/com.example.rachel.komunikator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-02 23:07:56.907 21212-21283/com.example.rachel.komunikator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-02 23:07:56.914 21212-21283/com.example.rachel.komunikator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-02 23:07:57.607 21212-21224/com.example.rachel.komunikator D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( lK8BXh5JpGQn3Mkq3hLpl6UWNru1 ).
```

[Android Monitor All error stack](http://pastebin.com/xj020J6y)

[Android Monitor All error stack - different emulator](http://pastebin.com/6U2Rm5Wm)

Comment: Let me just point out that you should be using the latest version of Firebase (10.0.1). Firebase Auth is known for not working when using previous versions of Firebase.

Comment: ok - So How Can I update my emulator to work with 10.0.1? How can I do it? When I try to run project with 10.0.1 i got error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> !zip.isFile()`

Comment: In most (maybe all) cases, the warning about _descriptor class not found_ is not an indication of a serious error that affects operation.  What is not working in your app?  Are you not able to create or log-in users?

Comment: You can use version 10.0.1 if you run with an API 23 or 24 emulator image.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41104004/4815718.  But you will still see the warning message on 10.0.1.  I see it with apps built with that version and don't have any problems with auth operations.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same issue today. As they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm), it was just a debug log which doesn't affect anything. While i was trying to create a user, i saw the same thing. The reason was that I was entering 4-char password. I've tried with 8 characters (I guess 6 is enough), problem solved.

Comment: Oh my God!!! This saved me.  Was using "pass" as password and changed it to "passpass" and it worked... hehehe... Thanks @Cagatay Barin

Comment: @MarkaA no problem dude, Error message should have some clarity though, it's so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following implementations:

implementation `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1`

implementation `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0`

In my case, I had two `Firebase.initializeApp()` statements in my code and the above error has occurred:

I could get rid of the error by removing one of the statements.