# Unable to create new user on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the code example on Firebase site. For some reason, I do not seem to get to onComplete method at all and get stuck after entering the if statement. Please advice. Thanks.

```
if(isRegistering){
    Log.d("TEST", "isRegistering"); // <- THIS PRINTS
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("TEST", "success"); // <- DOESN'T PRINT
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TEST", "fail"); // <- DOESN'T PRINT
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Update: Added gradle data.

Module:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

- Enable the authentication you are using in the console
  [image]
- Add the internet permission to the manifest

Comment: I've had email/password status enabled all the while. I added the internet permissions to manifest. But still getting same results.

Comment: The google services json file has been added under app folder and both gradle files been updated.

Comment: Check the logcat to see if it shows any warnings about firebase auth

Comment: Found follow error: "Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

Comment: Updated question to show my gradle file data. Looking at that question now.

Comment: Try with the auth version 9.6.1

Comment: Certainly an improvement. Changed it to 9.6.1 . Able to at least get into onComplete method but result is 'not successful. '

Comment: I guess that you are using the same user every time you try and it is giving a CollisionException, try one diferent

Comment: Good guess. Changed the username and works now. Thanks so much. Just not sure why I still get this error though: "Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found."

Comment: Take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023794/w-dynamitemodule-local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-firebase-auth-not

Comment: Nice one. Thanks.