# How can i fix SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want add **firebase** into my application and I added **firebase** with this path : `Tools -> Firebase` . 
But when run application show me this error in logs :

```
03-30 16:33:14.741 1457-1575/com.example.mohammad.a1_firstfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 6599430
03-30 16:33:14.742 1457-1457/com.example.mohammad.a1_firstfirebase W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
03-30 16:33:34.846 1457-2691/com.example.mohammad.a1_firstfirebase D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, retry in 60s
```

I added this dependencies :

```
{
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can I fix this problem? I need this help, please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100106/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-10084000-but-found-9879470-cant-upd

Comment: What you reported is a warning, not an error.
The device where you are testing doesn't have the latest version of the Google Play services app. Search it on the store and update it.
Anyway even without update FCM will work fine. But Analytics might not.

Answer (score -1):

add google-services.json file to your resource file